# Only update subscription if a new document is added in Meteorjs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a Messages collection which I publish. Now I want the local collection to update only if a new message is inserted. But if any of the messages get deleted, I don't want anything to happen to the local collections. I tried this:

```js
Meteor.publish('messages', function() {
  var self = this;

  Messages.find().observe({
    added: function(doc) {
      self.added('messages', doc._id);
    }
  });

  self.ready();

});
```

This works but the actual document doesn't get send to the client. In the browser if I run `Messages.find().fetch()`, I get this object back for each document:

```js
{
  _id: LocalCollection._ObjectID
  __proto__: Object
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a small mistake in your `added` function, you have to add the actual document as third parameter.

```
Messages.find().observe({
  added: function(doc) {
    self.added('messages', doc._id, doc);
  }
});
```

Comment: But the _id field is still missing.

Comment: @FardeemMunir I thought you only had the _id field before? Now you have all the document but the _id?

Comment: No like the _id field is now an object.

Comment: Never mind. I fixed it. It was something to do with running a separate mongo instance rather than the one that comes with meteor.